# python slice array produces different errors in several environments

Tags: python, list, slice

I have got 2 dev environment.

First I load the data into an array:

```
def loadData(filename):
    ins = open(filename, "r")
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(int(line))
   ins.close()
   return array
```

In the first one this works without problem

```
tempLeftArray = array[:(length / 2)]
tempRightArray = array[(length / 2):]
```

But in the second environment I have to change the code to the following because I was getting the 'slice indices must be integers or none or have __index__ method':

```
tempLeftArray = array[:int(length / 2)]
tempRightArray = array[int(length / 2):]
```

Dev env I : windows 8.1, visual studio 2013, python 3.4.0

Dev env II(error one): windows 7, visual studio 2013, python 3.4.0

Any idea of the problem with the first? Why do I need to change the code adding the cast?

Comment: Could it be length is a `float` in your second environment ? Try displaying `print repr(length), type(length)` and see what you get.

Comment: In Python 3, `length / 2` would be a float which would cause the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, division in Python 3, gives you floating number. And you cannot use a floating point number as a list's index.

You might want to use integer division in this case, like this

```
tempLeftArray  = array[:length // 2]
tempRightArray = array[length // 2:]
```

In Python 2.x,

```
print(4 / 2)
# 2
print(4.0 / 2)
# 2.0
print(4.0 // 2)
# 2.0
print(4 // 2)
# 2
```

In Python 3.4,

```
print(4 / 2)
# 2.0
print(4.0 / 2)
# 2.0
print(4.0 // 2)
# 2.0
print(4 // 2)
# 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps to avoid the use of specific casting, but then the question is why in one of my dev-env(both use python 3.4). I don't get the error... 
I'm new with python, so I don't know where should I check interpreter options.

Comment: @blacai In the first environment, you might have been Python 2.x. Can you please check with `python --version` in the command prompt?

Comment: oh... you're right. For some reason my visual studio changed the interpreter in the project's options.

I tried in a third environment and when I load the project the first time this option is not being set correctly.